# How do you change the phase of an electromagnetic wave?

Tags: electromagnetism

I was watching [a video on how cell service works](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0faCad2kKeg), and the author talks about three things we can change about a wave.

I understand that changing the amplitude is basically changing the brightness, by adding more power to the transmitter. We can also change the frequency, or the "color" of the wave, by basically exciting the underlying particles.

What I can't understand is how we can change a phase. Like do we interrupt the EM waves somehow to say "This is your new phase?"

Comment: Wendover Productions is an excellent channel with highly researched content on a range of topics. However, on this occasion, the treatment of the physics is sketchy at best; in particular, many of the waveforms shown (in the section on phase encoding) are unphysical. The overall ideas are OK, but the details are not - treat the description as a high-level caricature and an invitation to find out what actually happens with the signal.

Comment: I just watched the transmission half of the video. *Interruption* (or maybe you were looking for the word *delay*) may be a good way of looking at phase modulation. After all you're looking at periodic functions and with specific delays, you can connect different sections of e.g., a $\sin$ function to each other. What I recommend you to do however, is looking up amplitude modulation (AM), frequency modulation (FM), and phase modulation (PM) techniques (in a more detailed form). You may also look into digital modulations such as binary phase shift keying (BPSK).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to understanding the phase changes which occur in cell phone transmissions is to realize that the signals generated by the tower don't look always look like nice easy sine waves.  Take this example from [Physics and Radio-Electronics](https://www.physics-and-radio-electronics.com/blog/phase-modulation/):
[image: phase modulation]

Most of the time we're thinking of nice easy sine waves like the first two rows, but when we're adding in phase shifts, the results look more like the bottom.  In their particular example, they've chosen to modulate the phase every time the message signal goes from increasing to decreasing.

Such a circuit can be built rather easily.  When you wish to change the phase by 180 degrees, simply disconnect the wires from the antenna and connect them reversed.  It's easy to see that whenever the voltage would have been $v$, it must now be $-v$.  Obviously physically disconnecting the switches isn't going to fly at the speeds cell phones need.  We can wire up a double-pole double-throw switch to reverse voltages like this:
[image: Phase reverser]
This starts to automate the process, but still isn't fast enough.  If you get further into electronics, you will learn about devices that can switch a signal millions of times a second... transistors.  These are fast enough.

There is one trick to making these work well.  If you do your 180 degree phase transition at just any time, you might suddenly try to jump from 0.5V to -0.5V.  This introduces all sorts of artifacts as the circuits... well... rebel against the sudden discontinuity.  So cleverly, 180 degree phase shifts are only done at the points where the voltage is 0.  At this voltage, a 180 degree phase shift doesn't change the voltage, but it does change the direction the voltage is going.  (There are similar clever times for doing phase shifts other than 180 degrees)

The other thing to remember is that the cell phones don't have an ultra-accurate reference frequency generator that is magically "in phase" with the tower.  It can determine when the phase shifts (its easy to see in the graph), but it can't tell which phase is *supposed* to be 0 degrees and which phase is *supposed* to be 180 degrees.  We typically solve this digitally.  Before sending data, the tower transmits a string of known bits (like `101010101000000`).  The cell phone can see the rapid phase shifting in the first part, but can't tell `101` from `010`.  It figures out when the transitions take place, but doesn't know which transitions they are.  Then the tower sends several bits worth of data that are all 0.  Now the cellphone can signal that doesn't phase shift for quite some time (several nanoseconds).  Now, because we all agreed on this training signal, we know that those were 0's, and we can get our local signal generator exactly in phase with the towers.  After this, data transmission can take place.

But in the end, its like being out walking your dog on a leash.  If you want to change the direction the dog is walking, you just shift the direction you're leading with the leash.  No need to yank on them (typically).  Its just a change in the forces being applied.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm a bit confused. You say voltage can be negative?

Comment: @moonman239.  Yes, voltage can be negative.  Or at least that's how we electrical engineers say it.  If I want to be precise, I should only talk about voltage differences.   Technically there isn't such a thing as "the absolute voltage at point A,"  only "the difference in voltage between point A and B." I should say that the difference between the signal and the "ground" was negative (or, equivalently, that the ground was at a higher voltage than the signal).

Comment: However, that phrasing gets tedious, so typically we *assign* the "ground" to have an absolute voltage of 0V, and base everything around that.  As long as everybody agrees on the reference, we all get the right answer.  It works well for about 98% of electronics.  There are some corner cases, such as in hospitals, where there's a desire to *not* ground a patient, and in those cases we have to be extra careful and precise.